# Combine several rshiny apps into one

Tags: r, shiny

I have several shiny apps and i want to combine all of them into one app. However, i dont want to use the
`source()` function but instead i want do copy-paste the code for each shiny app. Now, if someone else run this app it gets an error. Any idea of how to do this?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("first_app", tabName = "first_app"),
      menuItem("second_app", tabName = "second_app")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "first_app",
              h2(source("sir.shiny.R", local = TRUE)$value)
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "second_app",
              h2(source("seir.shiny.R", local = TRUE)$value)
    )
  )
)
)
server <- function(input,output,server){}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Have a look at https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html

Comment: If you are not bound to `shinydashboard` you could give `flexdashboard` a try. It is really easy to embed many shiny apps into one with `flexdashboard`.

Comment: You can have apps run inside the network and connect to different ports. Are you expecting multiple users to to access the same app at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for this: Define all your functions above `ui` (or put them in `global.R`), and plot each model inside server function. Sidebar allows the user to pick the model of interest. See below.

```
##  Define your own functions above ui or inside global.R
mySEIR <- function(t, y, parms) {
  with(as.list(c(y, parms)),{
    
    # Change in Susceptibles
    dS <- - beta * S * I  
    # Change in Exposed
    dE <- beta * S * I - sigma * E
    # Change in Infecteds
    dI <- sigma * E - gamma * I
    # Change in Recovereds
    dR <- gamma * I  
    
    return(list(c(dS, dE, dI, dR)))
  })
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = div("Test SEIR app")),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
                menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("home")),
                menuItem("SIR", tabName = "first_app"),
                menuItem("SEIR", tabName = "second_app")
                )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "first_app", plotOutput("plotSIR")
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "second_app", plotOutput("plotSEIR")
      )
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output$plotSIR <- renderPlot({qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("red"),binwidth=0.2)})
  output$plotSEIR <- renderPlot({qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("blue"),binwidth=0.2)})
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```